# Synchronization MSSQL databases with selected data in .NET

Tags: c#, sql-server, microsoft-sync-framework

We have database SQL server 2008 (db A). For better performance we will use next SQL server 2008 databases with the one workgroup (db B, C, ...). These databases will contain only necessary records and will can save some special records. These all databases are always full SQL server, not express.

So we need to synchronize data from db A to db B, C. And then we need synchronize some data (with special sql query - for example only completed orders, not all) from db B to db A, from db C to db A, etc.

The synchronization should be console application.

I found some examples used MS Sync Framwork:

- SyncOrchestrator but I don't know how to select only some tables and some records.
- SyncTable but here I don't know how correct set RemoteProvider and LocalProvider to database SQL server 2008.

Is there any way how to solve it? Or how can I correct use sync?

Sorry for my english, it's not my native language.

Many thanks.

Comment: This may help you: http://msmvps.com/blogs/williamryan/archive/2007/11/13/filtering-data-ado-net-synchronization-services.aspx

Answer (score 1):

check out the walkthroughs here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928700(v=SQL.110).aspx

(the same walkthrough is in the documentation if you download Sync Framework 2.1)

that should get you up and running with defining a scope for your selected tables with filtering applied and specifying both local and remote providers as well. While the walkthrough says synchronizing between Sql Server and Sql Express, you can use the same for Sql Server to Sql Server synchronization as Sql Express, Sql Server and Sql Azure uses the same SqlSyncProvider.

Answer (score 0):

I would use SQL Server Replication http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx